# Jquery Datatable - displaying results but not assigning value to checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Had an issue the other day which would not display checkboxes however it now shows the checkbox but it is not assigning a value to the checkbox value attribute
based on the row id its just showing undefined

Here is my datatables jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#companylist').dataTable( {
   dom: '<lf> <t><ip><"clear">',
    ajax: {
    url: 'data/companylist-ajax.php',
    dataSrc: '',
  },

   bPaginate:true,
   scrollX: "100%",
   columnDefs: [ {
           orderable: false,
           className: 'select-checkbox',
           targets:   0
       } ],
       select: {
           style:    'os',
           selector: 'td:first-child'
       },
   order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
   scrollCollapse: true,
   bAutoWidth: true,

    aLengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ],
    select: true,
        "columns": [
          { data: null,
             render: function(data) {
             //return '<input type="checkbox" name="selectcompanyid">';
             return '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input checkboxdt" id="tableDefaultCheck"'+ data[0]+ '" value="'+ data[0]+ '"></div>';
             //return '<input class="checkboxdt" type="checkbox" name="test" value="' + data[0] +'">';
          }
        },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "regoffice_city" },
            { "data": "regoffice_country" },
            { "data": "is_customer" },
            { "data": "is_supplier" },
            { data: null,
               render: function(data) {
               return '<a class="" href="viewcompany.php?companyid=' + data[0] + '"><i class="far fa-fw fa-eye fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="" id="delcompanybtn" data-href="data/deletecompany.php?companyid=' + data[0] + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" data-id="' + data[0] + '"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash   fa-lg"></i></a>';
            }

          }
        ]
    } );

} );
```

Here is my AJAX page response :

```
[{"company_id":"181","name":"TEST 118","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"},{"company_id":"182","name":"TEST 119","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"},{"company_id":"75","name":"TEST 12","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"},{"company_id":"183","name":"TEST 120","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"},{"company_id":"184","name":"TEST 121","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"},{"company_id":"185","name":"TEST 122","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"},{"company_id":"186","name":"TEST 123","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"},{"company_id":"187","name":"TEST 124","regoffice_city":"","regoffice_country":"United Kingdom","is_customer":"0","is_supplier":"0"}]
```

Feel like im going round in circles now

Comment: instead of `data[0]` you should use `data`

Comment: data[0] is the 1st item thats pulled from the record 
data on its own does nothing

Comment: If you have a checkbox input, wouldn't you be looking to add a `checked` attribute and not value? How do you want the `checked` attr to be assigned? Based on ID? If yes, how?